# SQL - temp table for last 14 days of each month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a temp table based on a parameter that returns the last 14 days of every month in the given range. For example:

```
@StartDate = '20160101'
@EndDate = '20160401'
```

Then the temp table should contain the last 14 days (in date form) of Jan, Feb, Mar & Apr of 2016.

This is what I've tried:

```
WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT @Start AS Date, 
                CASE 
                  WHEN Datepart(mm, @Start) <> Datepart(mm, @Start + 1) THEN 1 
                  ELSE 0 
                END    AS [Last] 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT date + 1, 
                CASE 
                  WHEN Datepart(mm, date + 1) <> Datepart(mm, date + 2) THEN 1 
                  ELSE 0 
                END 
         FROM   cte 
         WHERE  date < @End) 
SELECT * 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  [last] = 1 
OPTION ( maxrecursion 0 )
```

Comment: but the last 14 days of april are outside the given range

Comment: This post doesn't really show any effort to resolve this issue on your part. What have you researched, tried, and found to not work?

Comment: You didn't give enough information to try to help you...

Comment: This was my attempt (it returns the last day of ever month in the range): With CTE as
(
Select @Start  as Date,Case When DatePart(mm,@Start)<>DatePart(mm,@Start+1) then 1 else 0 end as [Last]
UNION ALL
Select Date+1,Case When DatePart(mm,Date+1)<>DatePart(mm,Date+2) then 1 else 0 end from CTE
Where Date<@End
)

Select * from CTE
where [Last]=1   

OPTION ( MAXRECURSION 0 )

Comment: seems like a fair attempt to me - if we ask why the questioner hasn't further tried to correct his erroneous code, then he can never actually post a question, either he spends infinity trying new things, or otherwise finally gets it working.

Comment: @Cato when the question was first published it didn't show the "What I've tried:" nor the query below

Comment: @roberto - sorry I should have thought of that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    --generates all days belonging to all months in the range, then takes only the 
    --last 14 days of every month - dates outside of the range, but in those
    --actual months, can be valid to return
    DECLARE @StartDate date = '20160125';
    DECLARE @EndDate date = '20160401';

    WITH CTE AS (SELECT DATEADD(day,1 - day(@StartDate) , @StartDate) CD
                  UNION ALL SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, CD) FROM CTE WHERE CD < dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(m,1,dateadd(day,1 - day(@ENDDATE), @ENDDATE))))
        select * into #temp from CTE  WHERE DAY(dateadd(day,
                            -1,
                                dateadd(m,
                                        1,
                                        dateadd(day,
                                                1 - day(cd), 
                                                cd
                                                )
                                        )
                            )
                    ) - DAY(CD) < 14
        option (maxrecursion 0);
        select * from #temp;
```

Comment: Works great! THanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursive cte to generate all the dates in the given range.

Thereafter get the count of days for each month and subtract the day of month from that number and get the last 14 days (diff from 0 to 13) in each month.

```
declare @StartDate date = '2016-01-01';
declare @EndDate date = '2016-04-30';

With CTE as (Select @StartDate as start_date
             UNION ALL 
             Select dateadd(dd,1,start_date) from CTE Where start_date<@EndDate) 
select start_date
from (select *,count(*) over(partition by year(start_date),month(start_date)) days_in_month
      from CTE
     ) x
where days_in_month-datepart(dd,start_date) <=13
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

**[`Sample Demo`](http://rextester.com/VEAIL25471)**